# Windows Mobile 6.5 HD2 controls problem

Tags: windows-mobile

I have to develope app for my company on WM6.5 that deals XML (its not problem).

Framework: 3.5 C#
Device: HD2
Resolution: 480x800

Configured my VS2008, installed SDK 6, 6.5 DTK got Emulator 6.5.3

Got severals questions about controls.

```
1) Is it possible to set TabControl to left side, not bottom?
2) Is it possible to make expand/colapse panel? (Like click on "Cars" will expand to down panel or form) <=Important!
   a) Now im using Show/Hide panel
```

3) OpenSource/Free to use controls in company?

```
a) Found some controls on XDA Developers.
```

Question about conf VS2008

```
1) Is is possible to make phone and display area bigger?
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should separate this into different questions, since they are a bit disparate, but here are some answers:

1) No, the tab control is bottom-only on WinMo.  To get it to the top or side, you'd have to create a custom control.
2) No, the Panel is not natively collapsible.  To get a collapsable panel, you need a custom control.
3) This is vague.  You're after UI controls for the CF?  [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioMobile/), [BeeMobile](http://beemobile4.net/), [Resco](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx) and [PocketPCControls](http://www.pocketpccontrols.com/) all offer commercial controls.  If you're after free then you can use a search engine for the specific type of control you're after and places like CodeProject or blogs often will have something, though not always fully baked.  Remember, this platform has *way* fewer devs than the desktop, and getting people to produce high-quality code and then give it away is asking a lot.

As for the "Display area", do you mean the designer or emulator?  The emulator can do a 2x Zoom (in File -> Configure), but there nothing for "zooming" the designer.